# Does using a non-tradable tool on an item make it also non-tradable in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I have a non-tradable Artificer's Chisel that I got in one of those level present. I want to use it on an Immortal item that I have. However I'm not sure if it will make the Immortal item non-tradable aswell.

Comment: That's ridiculous.

Comment: well if you use a Polymorph scroll with a non-tradable item, it also makes the resulting item non-tradable. that's why I'm being caution and asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't, I've used a non tradable tool to create a gem socket on a courier and the courier is still tradable. However using a non tradable item in a crafting receipe will craft a non tradable item.

For any action that result in creating a non tradable item, you are promted a warning and a confirmation.